# Selecting an Item in a ComboBox affects an unrelated ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a XAML `UserControl` Which connects to a `ImportPresenter` ViewModel. There are four `ComboBox` items in my XAML:

1. `CashActivityTypeBAI` `CashActivityTypesCombo`, Which are bound to
   my    `CashActivityTypes` DataView
2. `CashActivitiesBAI` Which is bound to my    `BAICashActivites`
   DataView
3. `CashActivitiesCombo` Which is bound to    my `CashActivities`
   DataView.

I've included my XAML and three classes:

The `Presenter` and `ImportPresenter` are my ViewModels. There is a static `Controller` Class, which is used as my Model, that also connects to my DataSet.

**My Problem**

When an item is selected by either of the `CashActivityTypes` ComboBox items, their respective child DataViews are filtered. However, when either `CashActivityTypeBAI` or `CashActivityTypesCombo` are changed, it filters both child DataViews for both `CashActivity` comboboxes.

My XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cash_Sheet_WPF.Views.Pages.CheckBAIPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cash_Sheet_WPF.Views.Pages"
             xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:Cash_Sheet_WPF.Views.UserControls"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Cash_Sheet_WPF.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="534" d:DesignWidth="1184">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:ImportPresenter/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Cash Sheet WPF;component/backgroundA.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" MaxHeight="800"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UserControls:MainMenu Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,2,5,2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" FontSize="9" Content="Cash Activity Type"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CashActivityTypeBAI" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" FontSize="9" ItemsSource="{Binding CashActivityTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Type" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedBAIType}" SelectedValuePath="Sequence"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding CashActivityTypeIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" FontSize="9" Content="Cash Activity"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" FontSize="9"
                       Content="{Binding SelectedActivity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CashActivitiesBAI" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" FontSize="9"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding BAICashActivities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Activity"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedBAIActivity}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Sequence"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding CashActivityIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Individual Transactions" FontSize="9"/>
                <Label Content="Cash Activity Type" FontSize="9" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CashActivityTypesCombo" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="20" MinHeight="20" Background="White"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CashActivityTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Type"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding TypeSequence}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Sequence"
                          Margin="2,0,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Content="Cash Activity" FontSize="9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CashActivitiesCombo" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="20" MinHeight="20" Background="White"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CashActivities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Activity"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding ActivitySequence}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Sequence"
                          Margin="2,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `ImportPresenter` is a child of a `Presenter` Class

```
namespace Cash_Sheet_WPF.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main Presenter Class - Parent class of other presenters
    /// </summary>
    public class Presenter : ObservableObject
    {

        #region Variables

        protected DataView _CashActivityTypes = Controller.FinanceDB.CashActivityType.DefaultView;
        protected DataView _CashActivities = Controller.FinanceDB.CashActivity.DefaultView;
        protected short _TypeSequence;
        protected short _ActivitySequence;

        #endregion 


        #region Bindings

        //Returns a DataView from the CashActivityType table
        public DataView CashActivityTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return _CashActivityTypes;
            }
            set
            {
                _CashActivityTypes = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CashActivityTypes");
            }
        }//END CASHACTIVITYTYPES

        public DataView CashActivities
        {
            get
            {
                return _CashActivities;
            }
            set
            {
                _CashActivities = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CashActivities");
            }
        }//END CASHACTIVITIES

        public short TypeSequence
        {
            get
            {
                return _TypeSequence;
            }
            set
            {
                _TypeSequence = value;
                CashActivities.RowFilter = "Seq_CashActivityType = " + _TypeSequence;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("TypeSequence");
            }
        }//END TYPESEQUENCE

        #endregion

    }
}
```

`ImportPresenter` Class, which Extends the `Presenter` Class

```
namespace Cash_Sheet_WPF.ViewModels
{
    public class ImportPresenter : Presenter
    {

        #region Variables

        //BAI Adjustment
        private DataView _BAI;
        private DataRowView _BAIRow;
        private DataView _BAICashActivities = Controller.FinanceDB.CashActivity.DefaultView;
        private short _SelectedBAIType = 0;
        private short _SelectedBAIActivity = 0;


        private long _CashActivityTypeIndex = 0;
        private long _CashActivityIndex = 0;
        private decimal _BucketAmount = 0;

        #endregion 

        #region Bindings

        /// <summary>
        /// Cash Activities for the BAI Import Adjustment Section
        /// </summary>
        public DataView BAICashActivities
        {
            get
            {
                return _BAICashActivities;
            }
            set
            {
                _BAICashActivities = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BAICashActivities");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Selected Type index, to be used by the Combobox
        /// </summary>
        public long CashActivityTypeIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _CashActivityTypeIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                _CashActivityTypeIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CashActivityTypeIndex");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the index of the currently selected Cash Activity
        /// </summary>
        public long CashActivityIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _CashActivityIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                _CashActivityIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CashActivityIndex");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Selected Cash Activity Type
        /// </summary>
        public short SelectedBAIType
        {
            get { return _SelectedBAIType; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedBAIType = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedBAIType");
                BAICashActivities.RowFilter = "Seq_CashActivityType = " + _SelectedBAIType;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BAICashActivities");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Selected Cash Activity
        /// </summary>
        public short SelectedBAIActivity
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedBAIActivity;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedBAIActivity = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedBAIActivity");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Index of text in a DataView
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataView">DataView you are searching</param>
        /// <param name="stringItem">Search Text</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private long GetSelectedIndex(DataView dataView, string stringItem)
        {

            long selectedIndex = 0;
            foreach(DataRowView dataRowView in dataView)
            {
                if (dataRowView.Row.ItemArray.Contains(stringItem))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedIndex++;
                }
            }

            return selectedIndex;

        }

        #endregion 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've discovered what's happening, if anyone has this problem.

When you create two different `DataView` Objects based off the same `DataTable` object, a filter on one will always affect the other.

So instead of creating a new variable off of the same `DataTable`, I used the `GetData()` Function of the DataTable's `TableAdapter` and this worked out just fine.

```
private DataView _MyView1 = TableAdapter1.GetData().DefaultView;
private DataView _MyView2 = TableAdapter1.GetData().DefaultView;
```